# boost::asio using strand with thread_group only uses the first thread in the thread_group

Tags: c++, boost, asio

I am currently learning how to use and implement boost::asio.  I have been following a tutorial on gamedev.net at "https://www.gamedev.net/blogs/entry/2249317-a-guide-to-getting-started-with-boostasio/"

In this tutorial the following code is presented:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "/usr/include/boost/asio.hpp"
#include "/usr/include/boost/thread.hpp"
#include "/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp"

boost::mutex global_stream_lock;

void WorkerThread( boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::io_service > io_service )
{
    global_stream_lock.lock();
    std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id() << "] Thread Start" << std::endl;
    global_stream_lock.unlock();

    io_service->run();

    global_stream_lock.lock();
    std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id() << "] Thread Finish" << std::endl;
    global_stream_lock.unlock();


}

void PrintNum( int x )
{
    std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id() << "] x: " << x << std::endl;

}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::io_service > io_service(
            new boost::asio::io_service
    );
    boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::io_service::work > work(
            new boost::asio::io_service::work( *io_service )
    );
    boost::asio::io_service::strand strand (*io_service);


    global_stream_lock.lock();
    std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()
              << "] The program will exit when all work has finished." << std::endl;
    global_stream_lock.unlock();

    boost::thread_group worker_threads;
    for( int x = 0; x < 2; ++x )
    {
        worker_threads.create_thread( boost::bind( &WorkerThread, io_service ) );

    }


    boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::milliseconds( 1000 ) );

    strand.post( boost::bind( &PrintNum, 1 ) );
    strand.post( boost::bind( &PrintNum, 2 ) );
    strand.post( boost::bind( &PrintNum, 3 ) );
    strand.post( boost::bind( &PrintNum, 4 ) );
    strand.post( boost::bind( &PrintNum, 5 ) );

    work.reset();

    worker_threads.join_all();

    return 0;
}
```

My output when executing the code above:

```
[7fef17715000] The program will exit when all work has finished.
[7fef15897700] Thread Start
[7fef16098700] Thread Start
[7fef15897700] x: 1
[7fef15897700] x: 2
[7fef15897700] x: 3
[7fef15897700] x: 4
[7fef15897700] x: 5
[7fef15897700] Thread Finish
[7fef16098700] Thread Finish
```

My issue is that the code above only uses thread_id 7fef15897700 and 7fef16098700 is never used.  In the example tutorial, the output shows as follows:

```
[00154F88] The program will exit when all work has finished.
[001532B0] Thread Start
[00154FB0] Thread Start
[001532B0] x: 1
[00154FB0] x: 2
[001532B0] x: 3
[00154FB0] x: 4
[001532B0] x: 5
[00154FB0] Thread Finish
[001532B0] Thread Finish
```

I am using libboost 1.66 which is built was built as follows:

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr
./b2 install threading=multi
```

I am running debian as below:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

And an "lscpu | grep -i cpu" output:

```
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
CPU family:            6
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU         650  @ 3.20GHz
CPU MHz:               1197.000
CPU max MHz:           3193.0000
CPU min MHz:           1197.0000
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

How do I get the code to use all the available threads in the thread_group?

Thank you for any help or comments.

Comment: But this is the whole point of using a strand ... to only have one task executed at a time.  Post the items to the service directly if you don't care about their order

Comment: I think my misunderstanding comes from the fact that the code presented in the tutorial along with the output shows that there are multiple threads being used from the thread pool.  So does using strand then cause all of the work to be done using one thread?  If so what is the point of having the thread_group in the first place?

Comment: If you just want a single strand, and you want to put everything on it - there isn't any point in a thread group.  (You'll note though you're looking at a tutorial, which is showing you HOW to use it, not WHEN/WHY to use it).  If you have 100 strands however, you can have 4 threads process them all, and know that at most 1 task in each strand is being run at any one time (to the limit of your 4 threads).  Alternatively, you could have a single strand for something, but then pass most work directly to the service.

Comment: The motivation of the stand is to remove you having to implement your own mutex and have threads sleep waiting to take it; when instead they could be doing work and you don't need a mutex in the section at all.

Comment: Ok.  I understand.  It seems that the output provided in the tutorial showing different thread ids being used is not the output that matches the code when using strand.  Thanks for your help @UKMonkey